# Batch converts PDF to TIFF then runs through Tesseract, but only works with -debug configure

Tags: batch-file, pdf, imagemagick, tesseract, tiff

I have been working on a batch file that will ask for a file and output a TIFF version, using ImageMagick, to then be read by Tesseract. When working through problems with the conversion I kept `-debug configure` on my conversion so that I can keep track of where things were going wrong. Once I got everything working I deleted `-debug configure` and the batch file stopped working. When I replaced `-debug configure` it started working again. Isn't `-debug configure` just supposed to track the computer, or does it do something else? Thanks for all the help!

---

My code for reference:

```
@echo off
:start
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET WORK=C:\Users\Me
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\ProgramFiles\ImageMagick-6.9.1Q16;C;\ProgramFiles\gs\gs9.16
SET IMCONV="%PROGRAMFILES%\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\Convert"
SET TESS="%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Tesseract-OCR\Tesseract"
SET /p INPUTF=Input file(enter done if done)?
if %INPUTF%==done goto end
SET /p OUTPUTC=Output tiff file?
SET /p OUTPUTF=Output text file?
CD %WORK%
%IMCONV% -debug configure -density 300X300 %INPUTF% -auto-orient -depth 8 %OUTPUTC%
%Tess% %OUTPUTC% %OUTPUTF%
echo success
goto start
:end
```

Comment: Define "stopped working".

Comment: It displays the error `Cannot open input file:` however once i add -debug configure back in it can suddenly open the input file. This error happens at the Tesseract part of the code.